# What is alternative of colorControlNormal in MaterialComponents

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I'm trying to use `<item name="colorControlNormal">#66BB6A</item>` in `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` but not working so what is alternative without return to AppCompat?

Comment: https://material.io/blog/migrate-android-material-components

Comment: @ADM I saw this link but still don't know what is alternative. I still searching for 4 days ago

Comment: @ADM I think there is no alternative so can I use `com.google.android.material` with `Theme.AppCompat.Light`?

Comment: In which components are you trying to use it?